# NotificationListenerService in Android 4.4

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-4.4-kitkat

I have implemented a NotificationListenerService in my app, and int works fine in Jelly Bean. However that's not the case with KitKat, the reason, couldn't find the Notification Access settings, not anywhere.

So how should you be able to use this service when it doesn't seems like to be possible to enable Notification Access? Do you have to enable this programmatically or are there any other settings you must do in order to get this to work on KitKat?

**Edit**
Snippet from Android manifest containing the `NotificationListenerService` parts.

```
<service android:name="ax.ha.it.smsalarm.service.FlashNotificationService"
        android:label="@string/APP_NAME"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski - Added parts from manifest containing the relevant parts now. However I don't think that this is the problem as it works fine on Jelly Bean, the problem is that I don't find the Notification Access settings, nor in the emulator or my real device(Samsung Galaxy S4)